# Choose newline character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, eol

I notice that when I load a text file, Notepad++ will recognize and use whatever the newline character in that file is, `\n` or `\r\n`.

Is there some option where I can select which to use by default for new documents?
(I've looked in help and googled, but can't find anything.)

Answer (score 348, accepted):

For any new document: `Settings -> Preferences -> New Document (left pane) -> New Document (right pane) -> Format (Line ending) -> Windows (CR LF) / Unix (LF) / Macintosh (CR)`

And for an already-open document: `Edit -> EOL Conversion`

Comment: But note: in the the current version this only works when you create a new file with NP++. If you create an empty file it still seems to default to \r\n (when it finds no EOL characters to go by), and use that instead.

Comment: In version 7.7.1 this seems to default to the proper new document preferences.

Comment: You can also just double-click the format in the status bar and select the desired format. That's much easier than looking in the Edit menu. This also works in VSCode, with a single-click

Answer (score 85):

"Edit -> EOL Conversion". You can convert to Windows/Linux/Mac EOL there. The current format is displayed in the status bar.

Comment: This is much better

Comment: Upvoted just for mentioning the EOL format is shown in status bar (near bottom-right of default configured Notepad++ window).

Comment: You can also just double-click the format in the status bar and select the desired format. That's much easier.

Answer (score 4):

on windows 10, Notepad 7.8.5, i found this solution to convert from CRLF to LF.
`Edit > Format end of line`
and choose either `Windows(CR+LF)` or `Unix(LF)`

Answer (score 2):

Just double-click on that EOL format in the status bar and select Unix(LF).
It's not possible to default save a file in this (`LF`) format.

[image: How to change the EOL format in Notepad++.]

Just an alternative to the "new document" setting mentioned earlier …

Comment: My guess is that the reason this answer has attracted downvotes is that this feature is no longer available in the versions of the last few years. I tried it in version 8.4.6 (32-bits), and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Henke Seems to work for me, and I'm running the latest version.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit? Maybe not relevant?
When I have the time, I will update to the latest version to see if that makes any difference.