# multiple line code becomes one line code on remote server

Tags: codeigniter, alignment, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ for a long time and i am suffering from a problem on code alignment.When i upload my project to the remote server then my multiple line code becomes one line code and for this reason i have to align the code after uploading it to remote server neither i get errors.One thing to mention that i have tried almost 5-10 different servers to check my project but all the time my code becomes one line code.where is the actual problem and how to fix this i am in deep trouble i have a project of over 1000 files and it is not possible to align all the lines.please help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have a newline character problem. Different operating systems use different newline characters. Your Notepad++ might be configured to use one that works on your machine, but not on the servers you use.

This might help: [Choose newline character in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195839/choose-newline-character-in-notepad)

Also, check how the original CI files behave (not the ones you've edited).