# Break Returns Stripped when uploading to server

Tags: php, ftp, notepad++

When using notepad++ to edit a PHP file, new lines are ignored. So if I put a comment in place using "//some comment" any code that proceeds the comment is ignored by the PHP parser.

Netbeans works fine. I assume it's something do to with the line endings in notepad++?

Does anyone have a quick fix?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choose newline character in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195839/choose-newline-character-in-notepad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change the end of line character in your file.

Notepad++ allows you to change this setting. IIRC there is an option called 'EOL Convention' with a fly-out for Windows / Mac / Linux  in the Edit menu.