# bash not parsing (cat + grep) correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, cygwin

I have a text file `1.grep`

```
grep -P -e "^<job.+type.+rule" "Emake-4agents-1st-10-25-51.53.xml"
```

To make my grepping go faster, I do the following in `bash`

`cat 1.grep | bash > 1.search`

This works fine *normally* but in this case, I get the following:

```
$ cat 1.grep
grep -P -e "^<job.+type.+rule" "Emake-4agents-1st-10-25-51.53.xml"

$ cat 1.grep | bash > 2.search
: No such file or directory25-51.53.xml
```

Why does `bash` think that my `.xml` filename is a directory?

Comment: you don't want to do `cat foo|bash`, you can make the `foo` as a shell script with hashbang, and `+x`

Comment: `cat`_ing_ to `bash` won't help.  Just do `grep -P -e "^<job.+type.+rule" "Emake-4agents-1st-10-25-51.53.xml"  > 1.search`

Comment: @agc this is not practical when I have many other parameters. This is a trivial example.

Comment: `bash 1.grep` will execute the command in 1.grep. Why do you need the cat ?

Comment: @matzeri you're right it does. Problem is I still get the same error `$ bash 1.grep
: No such file or directory25-51.53.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the file 1.grep is in DOS/Windows format, and has a carriage return followed by linefeed at the end of the line. Windows treats that two-character combination as the end-of-line marker, but unix tools like `bash` (and `grep` and ...) will treat just the linefeed as the end-of-line marker, so the carriage return is treated as part of the line. As a result, it's trying to read from a file named "Emake-4agents-1st-10-25-51.53.xml^M" (where `^M` indicates the carriage return), which doesn't exist, so it prints an error message with a carriage return in the middle of it:

```
cat: Emake-4agents-1st-10-25-51.53.xml^M
: No such file or directory
```

...where the carriage return makes the second part overwrite the first part, giving the cryptic result you saw.

Solution: use something like `dos2unix` to convert the file to unix (line-feed-only) format, and use text editors that store in the unix format.

However, I also have to agree with several comments that said using `cat | bash` is ... just plain weird. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish in the bigger picture, but I can't think of any situation where that'd be the "right" way to do it.

Comment: yay! thanks. I use notepad++ extensively and I followed this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195839/choose-newline-character-in-notepad to always have it use `\n` for new line. `bash <text_file>` works now.

Comment: For future reference, you can always use `tr` (or sed) to get rid of the ^M characters: `tr '\r' '\n' < file.txt`. Also, as said before, avoid the use of `cat file | something else. Google UUOC :)