# Getting issue with .bash_profile in linux

Tags: linux, classpath, bash

I am trying set class path but getting error.

**File Code :**

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin


PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

It print BLANK when I echo Java classpath.

When I access server via putty , Getting error :

**-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: /home/test/.bash_profile: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error may related to the CRLF and CR [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), you may resolve this by edit the file in linux side or using a rich editor such as notepad++ which you can save using Linux newline, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8195860/5793435)

Beside, you may want to write those scripts in .bashrc

The bash man page on my linux box says:

```
FILES
   /bin/bash
          The bash executable
   /etc/profile
          The systemwide initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bash_profile
          The personal initialization file, executed for login shells
   ~/.bashrc
          The individual per-interactive-shell startup file
   ~/.bash_logout
          The individual login shell cleanup file, executed when  a  login
          shell exits
   ~/.inputrc
          Individual readline initialization file
   /etc/inputrc
          System readline initialization file
```

according to this [post](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html), the terminal.app on OS X is an exception.

```
Mac OS X — an exception
An exception to the terminal window guidelines is Mac OS X’s 
Terminal.app, which runs a login shell by default for each new
terminal window, calling .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. Other 
tGUI terminal emulators may do the same, but most tend not to.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `dos2unix .bash_profile` to convert Windows new line into UNIX new line.