# Encoding text URL

Tags: java, character-encoding

Below is my text

```
Test[LF]
[LF]
Test[LF]
[LF]
Test[LF]
Test[LF]
```

In notepad++ after enabling show symbol its showing `[LF]` symbol as displayed in above.

When endococing above text it showing as below

```
Test%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%0D%0A%0D%0ATest%0D%0ATest

[LF] encoded as %0D%0A
```

My question is why is encoded as `%0D%0A`? Because `[LF]` encode as `%OA`

where as `[CR]` encode as `[%OD]` but in above text I am not used `[CR]` character.

Comment: My guess is that for some reason there really are carriage returns in your text, which is why you see them when the text is encoded.

Comment: But after ebabing show symbol only LF character is showing

Comment: I don't know what "ebabing" is.

Comment: Its a type mistake. After on show all symbol in notepad++

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Java class to find out each byte of your input file:
    package example;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileBytes {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Please provide one argument" );
        }
        File f = new File( args[0] );
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( Files.readAllBytes( f.toPath() ) ) );
    }
}
```

You'll see something like this:

```
[84, 101, 115, 116, 10, 84, 101, 115, 116, 10]
```

You can see what each value means in an [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) if you're lucky and your file is encoded with UTF-8 or ASCII and only contains ASCII characters (if not, then translating bytes to characters will be quite complicated - look up about the particular encoding you're using).

For example, `84 == T` and `10 == LF (Line Feed)`, so you could translate the above to `Test(LF)Test(LF)`.

To escape the whole String in the file so it's safe to use in a URL, use `URLEncoder` as in this example:

```
package example;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FileBytes {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        if ( args.length != 1 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Please provide one argument" );
        }
        File f = new File( args[ 0 ] );
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes( f.toPath() );
        String rawText = new String( bytes, "UTF-8" );
        String encodedText = URLEncoder.encode( rawText, "UTF-8" );

        System.out.println( "Raw text: " + rawText );
        System.out.println( "Encoded text: " + encodedText );
        System.out.println( "Raw bytes: " + Arrays.toString( bytes ) );
        System.out.println( "Encoded bytes: " + Arrays.toString( encodedText.getBytes() ) );
        System.out.println( Arrays.toString( bytes ) );
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Raw text: Test
Test

Encoded text: Test%0ATest%0A
Raw bytes: [84, 101, 115, 116, 10, 84, 101, 115, 116, 10]
Encoded bytes: [84, 101, 115, 116, 37, 48, 65, 84, 101, 115, 116, 37, 48, 65]
```

Which clearly shows that the line-feed (`10`) is encoded as `%0A` (`37, 48, 65`).

If you still see `%0D (Carriage Return)` in the bytes, your editor is adjusting line-endings automatically to match Windows' convention. There's an [option in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195839/choose-newline-character-in-notepad) to select line-endings explicitly.

Comment: Actually, instead of an ASCII table, the user has to consult the table for the character encoding that the file was saved with—very unlikely to be ASCII.

Comment: Definitely. But someone trying to figure out line-endings probably won't care about the encoding too much :)

Comment: I was assuming UTF-8 actually - and given the example in the question, the file is likely to contain only ASCII characters - as UTF-8 looks like ASCII in case that's true, there seems to be no need to complicate the answer with details about encoding.

Comment: ASCII is an encoding, probably the wrong one. That seems to complicate things to me.

Comment: I added an edit to make it clear the encoding might be important.